# How to write a constraint to find the index of the min value in a set?

Tags: linear-programming

Consider this example with set A={100,50,150}. Min value in this set is 50. How to find out that the index of 50 is 2 in this set?
I need 2 as the answer to put it in another constraint

Comment: Are the entries in $A$ variables in your model?

Comment: Yes , A variables are answer of another constraint ! I want find index of min between them to put index number as input in next constraint .@prubin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it likely would be an algorithmic way rather than being an optimization model. B.T.W, you can do what you want by the following MIP model:

\begin{array}{l}
\text{Min} \ z = \sum_{i} A.val_i*x_i\\
\text{subject to:} \\
\sum_i x_i = 1\\
y_i = i .x_i \quad i=1, \ldots, m\\
x_{i} \in\{0,1\}, y_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \quad i\in m\\
\end{array}

As a simple example, with your data, the results are:

```
----     15 VARIABLE min_.L                =       50.000  

----     15 VARIABLE x.L  

50 1.000


----     15 VARIABLE y.L  

50 2.000
```

Comment: Or may be like                                                                                                                $\max \sum_i a_ix_i$
s.t.
$\sum_i a_ix_i \le a_i \quad \forall i= 1...n$                                                                                 and ofcourse $y_i = \sum_i ix_i$

Comment: I think its need sum(i in n) x[i]=1; isnt it ?

Comment: Since the A values are variables, the objective here is (nonconvex) quadratic. Fortunately, it can be linearized by the usual tricks, assuming that finite a priori bounds for the A variables exist.